# Change pc password with command prompt

Tags: windows-10, prompt

Welcome , today I'm working with the command prompt on Windows 10 , I like to know if it is possible to change my pc's password with this and how can I do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need administrative privileges and you need to know your username.

From the command prompt, enter the following command, and replace `<username>` with your actual username:

```
net user <username> *
```

Then enter the new password.

Do note, it will not ask to reconfirm your password, so any typo can mean the end of logging in.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Change Local Password from Command Line

```
net user <username> <NewPassword>
```

---

### 2. Change Domain Password from Command Line

```
net user <username> <NewPassword> /Domain
```

**Note:** *Be sure to run this from an elevated command prompt.*

**Important:** *You will need AD level permission to change your own password apparently via this method so this command may more easily be usable by domain admins; otherwise, further AD permissions.*

**Error**

> ```
> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.
> ```

[image]

### 3. Alternatively

You can press <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Del`</kbd> and select **Change Password** for a GUI method to change your own password on a domain PC when you're not a domain admin.

### [image]

### Further Resources

- [Net User](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Change *Domain Password* with net use does not work with own password and if not domain admin!

Comment: @FalcoAlexander FYI... I've updated to indicate more clearly that issue you mentioned and reported on this post. Let me know if this pacifies your concern and expresses more clearly of this issue you reported.

Comment: afaik "You will need AD level permission to change your own password apparently via this method" is not correct or enough. the only method that worked for me as non AD Admin by script is the Powershell command from the RBAC tools, not installed by default.

Comment: Thus the #3 alternative which I provided for AD non-domain admin accounts. Regular non-admin users in an AD environment typically won't change their password via a script & will more likely use a GUI method. At least for the ten thousands of end-user I've supported over my years in AD environments, they change at login as prompted upon password expiring or press Alt+Ctrl+Del or Alt+Ctrl+End via RDP or terminal services. I answered this question long ago right at the same time the other answers were provided so I just added the domain method as additional but yes, I've always been domain admin.

Comment: in my case I searched for a method to chance my AD password, and UI was not an option because I could not type the generated password with a german keyboard layout :)

Answer (score 0):

`net user <your username> *`

You will be prompted to enter your new password.
Replace `<your username>` with your logon name (and don't type the <> characters).