# How can I change (not reset) another user's Windows password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, microsoft-account

I'm trying to change the password of a local account on a non-domain Windows 10 PC.

Logging in as the user to do the change is a poor solution because:

- Local login is denied for the account
- Entering the password into the login screen would be difficult due to its length and presence of characters not on a standard keyboard

I would have normally used the "Change *a* password" option on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> screen ([it's not just for your account](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180710-00/?p=99205)), but it doesn't show up for me. The group policy setting that controls whether it's shown is set appropriately. A quick experiment seems to suggest that it's always hidden when logged in with a Microsoft account.

Comment: Any keyboard should be able to produce any OS supported character.

Comment: Can you log on as local administrator?  If so you can change another users password as described here (just use the other account name instead of your own) https://superuser.com/questions/1212911/change-pc-password-with-command-prompt#1212916